# Is there any reason I wouldn't link a program immediately in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, language-agnostic

In OpenGL, would there be any use case where I would create a program, attach whatever shaders I want, call any of the pre-link operations like `glBindAttribLocation`, `glBindFragDataLocation​`, `glTransformFeedbackVaryings`, or `glProgramParameter`, and then not link it immediately after that?

Is there any reason to keep an unlinked program object around, even if I do link it at some later point?

Comment: I think this question cannot really be answered in a meaningful way. The program object needs to have been sucessfully linked before it can be used, and that it is all there is, as far as the GL is concerned.